# Jupyter notebook kernel died (memory shortage)

Tags: memory, anaconda, jupyter, keras

I have a problem when I use keras model (deep learning library) in Jupyter notebook.
This problem occurred after I installed scipy, matplotlib libraries in conda.
Before executing code cell, my computer GPU memory usuage is 241 MB / 8113 MB

And I executed simple keras model code like below

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution1D, MaxPooling1D, Activation, Dense, Flatten

# Parameter
n_filters1 = 64 # number of convolutional filters
n_filters2 = 32
n_conv = 4    # convolution filter size
n_pool = 3    # pooling window size

model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution1D(n_filters1, n_conv, border_mode='valid', activation='relu', input_shape=(40, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(n_pool, stride=2))
model.add(Convolution1D(n_filters2, n_conv, border_mode='valid', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(n_pool, stride=2))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

After executing above code, GPU memory usage change from 241MB -> 7754MB

So, when I run training cell code, Jupyter died

This problem happened again and again... even though I restarted my Jupyter notebook...

Is there any good idea to solve this problem?

Comment: this is all the code you executed? you didn't run `compile` or `fit` function on the model?

Comment: Yes, i run just above code. I solved the problem. I added GPU memory usage code before run keras model code. Thanks~